# Why grDevices color modifiers don't work in `rug()` and `axis()` in R?

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have noticed several `graphics` functions (e.g., `rug()`) do not work with `grDevices` color modifying functions (e.g., `adjustcolor()`, `rgb()` etc.). Below, I provide some examples.

## Question

Now that `adjustcolor()` and `rgb()` do not work, I was wondering in the case of `rug()` (see below), how I can produce the ***transparency effect*** (aka `alpha` parameter) in my `rug()` calls below?

## Update:

Even when I run our colleague's, **@AkselA**, `rug()` code (see his answer below) I can not replicate his results. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
x = rnorm(1e2)
hist( x )

 rug( x , col = adjustcolor("pink" , .5) ) # Doesn't work
 rug( x , col = rgb(1, 0, 0 , .5       ) ) # Doesn't work

 axis(1 , col = adjustcolor("pink" , .5) ) # Doesn't work
 axis(1 , col = rgb(1, 0, 0 , .5       ) ) # Doesn't work

plot( x , col = adjustcolor("pink" , .5) ) # works
plot( x , col = rgb(1, 0, 0 , .5       ) ) # works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work perfectly for me, as it should, because the output of those two functions is just a simple rgb hex string, which is pretty much universally accepted as a colour argument in R functions.

```
x = rnorm(1e2)

par(mfrow=c(1, 3), mar=c(2, 2, 2, 1))
hist(x)
rug(x, col = adjustcolor("red", 1), ticksize=0.05, lwd=0.6)

hist(x)
rug(x, col = adjustcolor("red", 0.3), ticksize=0.05, lwd=0.6)

hist(x); adjustcolor("red", 0.3)
rug(x, col = "#ff00004D", ticksize=0.05, lwd=0.6)
```

[image]

Maybe something's up with the device. What happens if you try

```
png("rugRedTransparent.png", 550, 400)
hist(x)
rug(x, col = "#FF00004D", ticksize=0.05, lwd=1)
dev.off()
```

?

Comment: Bu still when I run your `rug()` code for the middle and right-most histograms, I do not get results like your. It becomes completely colorless, and nothing shows.

Comment: @parvinkarimi: Odd. Does `hist(x, col="#ff00004D")` still produce the expected result?

Comment: Like I said, `hist(x, col="#ff00004D")` works, but `rug(x, col="#ff00004D")` doesn't work at all.